# ssh public key auth: first login still asks for a password

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

I have set up public key authentication with `ssh`, but what happens, is that when I first log in, it still asks for a password, any subsequent login (while keeping the first login alive), does not ask for a password. I am not aware of any settings that produce such a behavior. Anybody any ideas why I am prompted for a password the first time?

The password is surely not the password to access the key, as I get the `ssh` login message from the server and I am asked for the `user@remote` password.

EDIT:
output of `ssh -vvv user@remote`:

first logon:

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/[user]/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/[user]/.ssh/config line 34: Applying options for phremote
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Hostname has changed; re-reading configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/[user]/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to [remotehost] [[remotehost]] port [remoteport].
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/[user]/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/[user]/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/[user]/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/[user]/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/[user]/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/[user]/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/[user]/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/[user]/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/[user]/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: put_host_port: [[remotehost]]:[remoteport]
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[[remotehost]]:[remoteport]" from file "/home/[user]/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/[user]/.ssh/known_hosts:31
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA ca:f9:c6:2e:47:dc:02:79:bd:22:db:8d:d0:a3:df:a5
debug3: put_host_port: [[remotehost]]:[remoteport]
debug3: put_host_port: [[remotehost]]:[remoteport]
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[[remotehost]]:[remoteport]" from file "/home/[user]/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/[user]/.ssh/known_hosts:31
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[[remotehost]]:[remoteport]" from file "/home/[user]/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/[user]/.ssh/known_hosts:31
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host '[[remotehost]]:[remoteport]' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/[user]/.ssh/known_hosts:31
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/[user]/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f54f7b2d480),
debug2: key: /home/[user]/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/[user]/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/[user]/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
debug3: input_userauth_banner

[server ssh logon greeting message]

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/[user]/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/[user]/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/[user]/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/fbence/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/fbence/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/fbence/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/fbence/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
[remoteuser]@[remotehost]'s password: 

debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 58 padlen 6 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 81.182.242.26 ([81.182.242.26]:2222).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env NVM_RC_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env CAML_LD_LIBRARY_PATH
debug3: Ignored env XDG_VTNR
debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = hu_HU.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env MANPATH
debug3: Ignored env NVM_IOJS_ORG_VERSION_LISTING
debug1: Sending env LC_ADDRESS = hu_HU.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR
debug3: Ignored env SELINUX_INIT
debug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = hu_HU.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env CLUTTER_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env COMP_WORDBREAKS
debug3: Ignored env SESSION
debug3: Ignored env ANDROID_HOME
debug3: Ignored env GPG_AGENT_INFO
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env VTE_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env XDG_MENU_PREFIX
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env PERL5LIB
debug3: Ignored env WINDOWID
debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = hu_HU.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env UPSTART_SESSION
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL
debug3: Ignored env GTK_MODULES
debug3: Ignored env OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH
debug3: Ignored env NVM_DIR
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug1: Sending env LC_TELEPHONE = hu_HU.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_PATH
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SEAT_PATH
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env KRDIR
debug3: Ignored env DEFAULTS_PATH
debug3: Ignored env SESSION_MANAGER
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CONFIG_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env DESKTOP_SESSION
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env QT_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME
debug3: Ignored env NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
debug1: Sending env LC_IDENTIFICATION = hu_HU.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env JOB
debug3: Ignored env XMODIFIERS
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_KEYRING_PID
debug1: Sending env LANG = hu_HU.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env GDM_LANG
debug3: Ignored env MANDATORY_PATH
debug1: Sending env LC_MEASUREMENT = hu_HU.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE
debug3: Ignored env IM_CONFIG_PHASE
debug3: Ignored env PAPERSIZE
debug3: Ignored env GDMSESSION
debug3: Ignored env SESSIONTYPE
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SEAT
debug3: Ignored env LANGUAGE
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env COMPIZ_BIN_PATH
debug3: Ignored env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
debug3: Ignored env XDG_DATA_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env QT4_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env NVM_IOJS_ORG_MIRROR
debug3: Ignored env INSTANCE
debug3: Ignored env TEXTDOMAIN
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env GTK_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env LESSCLOSE
debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = hu_HU.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env TEXTDOMAINDIR
debug1: Sending env LC_NAME = hu_HU.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env XAUTHORITY
debug3: Ignored env COLORTERM
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
```

second (or any subsequent logon):

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/[user]/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/[user]/.ssh/config line 34: Applying options for phremote
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Hostname has changed; re-reading configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/[user]/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to [remoteip] [[remoteip]] port [remoteport.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/[user]/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/[user]/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/[user]/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/[user]/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/[user]/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/[user]/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/[user]/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/[user]/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/[user]/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: put_host_port: [[remoteip]]:[remoteport
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[[remoteip]]:[remoteport" from file "/home/[user]/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/[user]/.ssh/known_hosts:31
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA ca:f9:c6:2e:47:dc:02:79:bd:22:db:8d:d0:a3:df:a5
debug3: put_host_port: [[remoteip]]:[remoteport
debug3: put_host_port: [[remoteip]]:[remoteport
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[[remoteip]]:[remoteport" from file "/home/[user]/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/[user]/.ssh/known_hosts:31
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[[remoteip]]:[remoteport" from file "/home/[user]/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/[user]/.ssh/known_hosts:31
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host '[[remoteip]]:[remoteport' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/[user]/.ssh/known_hosts:31
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/[user]/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7fc9d08bf480),
debug2: key: /home/[user]/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/[user]/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/[user]/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
debug3: input_userauth_banner

[server ssh logon message]

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/[user]/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp a6:51:bb:ea:bc:4d:32:94:29:6e:d0:d4:f3:45:5b:a6
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA a6:51:bb:ea:bc:4d:32:94:29:6e:d0:d4:f3:45:5b:a6
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to [remoteip] ([[remoteip]]:[remoteport).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env NVM_RC_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env CAML_LD_LIBRARY_PATH
debug3: Ignored env XDG_VTNR
debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = hu_HU.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env MANPATH
debug3: Ignored env NVM_IOJS_ORG_VERSION_LISTING
debug1: Sending env LC_ADDRESS = hu_HU.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR
debug3: Ignored env SELINUX_INIT
debug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = hu_HU.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env CLUTTER_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env COMP_WORDBREAKS
debug3: Ignored env SESSION
debug3: Ignored env ANDROID_HOME
debug3: Ignored env GPG_AGENT_INFO
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env VTE_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env XDG_MENU_PREFIX
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env PERL5LIB
debug3: Ignored env WINDOWID
debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = hu_HU.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env UPSTART_SESSION
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL
debug3: Ignored env GTK_MODULES
debug3: Ignored env OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH
debug3: Ignored env NVM_DIR
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug1: Sending env LC_TELEPHONE = hu_HU.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_PATH
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SEAT_PATH
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env KRDIR
debug3: Ignored env DEFAULTS_PATH
debug3: Ignored env SESSION_MANAGER
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CONFIG_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env DESKTOP_SESSION
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env QT_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME
debug3: Ignored env NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
debug1: Sending env LC_IDENTIFICATION = hu_HU.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env JOB
debug3: Ignored env XMODIFIERS
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_KEYRING_PID
debug1: Sending env LANG = hu_HU.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env GDM_LANG
debug3: Ignored env MANDATORY_PATH
debug1: Sending env LC_MEASUREMENT = hu_HU.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE
debug3: Ignored env IM_CONFIG_PHASE
debug3: Ignored env PAPERSIZE
debug3: Ignored env GDMSESSION
debug3: Ignored env SESSIONTYPE
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SEAT
debug3: Ignored env LANGUAGE
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env COMPIZ_BIN_PATH
debug3: Ignored env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
debug3: Ignored env XDG_DATA_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env QT4_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env NVM_IOJS_ORG_MIRROR
debug3: Ignored env INSTANCE
debug3: Ignored env TEXTDOMAIN
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env GTK_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env LESSCLOSE
debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = hu_HU.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env TEXTDOMAINDIR
debug1: Sending env LC_NAME = hu_HU.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env XAUTHORITY
debug3: Ignored env COLORTERM
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
```

Comment: The first login **after** you installed your public key on the target server?

Comment: Output of `ssh -vvv user@host` would be helpful. Sounds like the remote side doesn't have or doesn't like your key.

Comment: @phk No, to be more clear: I have to open an ssh tunnel which prompts me for a password, any subsequent ssh tunnels are opened passwordless, as long as I keep my first tunnel open.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably caused by the fact, that your home directory (and therefore the key) is not accessible during the login time. This can be caused by the fact, that your home is mounted from network drive (on shared system) after login or your home directory is encrypted (usually installs of workstations).

Solving this is complicated, but I will have a look for some discussion. Solution is to move the `AuthorizedKeysFile` to some other place, that will be accessible or us global store for keys (`/etc/security/authorized_keys`), or some kind of SSO management system (IPA, LDAP), which will get your key from directory server (yes, can be local). Depends on how much control of the target system you have.

Probably best solution is to store your keys in other place, changing the value in `sshd_config`:

```
AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/%u/authorized_keys
```

Further discussion is available on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/61057/ssh-with-authorized-keys-to-an-ubuntu-system-with-encrypted-homedir) or here on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47122/cant-do-ssh-public-key-login-under-encrypted-home), or description on [help.Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys#Troubleshooting).

Comment: I moved the authorized keys as you suggested to `/etc/ssh/%u/authorized_keys` and now the login works fine, but my `bashrc` isn't read, I lost my fancy prompt :) Hmm, more like it seems that my home was not even decrypted. This doesn't seem like what I would want. Can this be solved with public key authentication with an encrypted home or not really?

Comment: not for the first or for all the logins? It worked before for first or for both?

Comment: Okay, so I found `/sbin/mount.ecryptfs_private` which gives me an error saying `Signature not found in user keyring
Perhaps try the interactive 'ecryptfs-mount-private'`. Which does decrypt the directory, but doesn't source the bashrc. I could write a script that does this though, so in the end I would be back at passwordless login, but having to type in my password anyway, to have my usual setup.

Comment: It didn't source it for the first login, and sourced it for any subsequent login. So again, the decryption. But it seems you can't really skip supplying the password in the end.

Comment: Probably I will have to make a new question about the best way to solve this problem :)