# Sharing ssh keys between cluster nodes

Tags: linux, ssh, key-authentication, cluster

I have a cluster with several login nodes and many compute nodes (call it the **cluster**). Then I have another server with a large shared storage (call it the **storage**). I need to be able to `rsync` (i.e. `ssh`) from any node on the **cluster** to the **storage**. For that, I generated a private-public key pair on one of the headnodes of the **cluster** and registered that key with the **storage**.

At first, `ssh`-ing prompts for the password but any subsequent `ssh` works without the password. However, if I switch hosts on **cluster** (for example, landing on a different login node or `ssh`-ing from one of the compute nodes), then **storage** asks for the password again. Subsequent `ssh` connections from the same **cluster** host work, but the moment I switch hosts, the password is prompted again one more time.

I was wondering whether this could be a security setting on **storage** or there is anything specific to be done when sharing the same keys between multiple nodes to prevent this happening? I don't have root access to either **cluster** or **storage** and I cannot decide which nodes on **cluster** are assigned to me at runtime.

I believe my question is related to [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238568/ssh-public-key-auth-first-login-still-asks-for-a-password) because my home directory (where the keys are located) is remotely mounted on the cluster nodes.

Comment: Any reason for not generating an ssh key pair on every node and registering that on the storage?

Comment: @YoMismo, yes. I only have access to the nodes during runtime; after that, all data on the nodes is lost, so I cannot save the keys on the nodes.

Comment: then what you are doing doesn't have any sense, if you generate a key, register that key, then when you change node and return back to the first one the key will be lost, so you can't use the shared key method to access the storage. I don't know what you can and can't do, but `expect` might come in handy.